# Hyperparameter optimization of MLPRegressor in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am very new in machine learning using python and would appreciate any help with the following problem.

I am trying to run MLPRegressor for list of different hidden neuron numbers (6 values) and for each selected neuron number I want the training data to be shuffled three times, i.e. three scores for each neuron number. The following code works fine and returns 18 scores (6*3). However I feel it is not the efficient way of solving the problem, since it is running almost an hour. I have tried using GridSearchCV(), but I don't know how to control shuffling of the training data (3 times for each hidden neuron numbers). Can anybody suggest a better (faster) way of solving this?

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

n=3 # how many times to shuffle the training data
nhn_range=[8,10,12,14,16,18] # number of hidden neurons

nhn_scores = []
for nhn in nhn_range:
    mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(nhn,), activation='tanh', 
                       solver='adam', shuffle=False, random_state=42, 
                       max_iter=20000, momentum=0.7, early_stopping=True, 
                       validation_fraction=0.15)
    for _ in range(n):
        df_train = shuffle(df_train)
        score = np.sqrt(-cross_val_score(mlp, df_train[feature_cols], 
                        df_train[response_cols], 
                        cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')).mean()
        nhn_scores.append(score)
```

The code returns a list of scores. How can I get a simple data frame with 3 rows (for each shuffling) and 6 columns (for each hidden neuron number).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
score_dict = {}
for nhn in nhn_range:
    mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(nhn,), activation='tanh', 
                       solver='adam', shuffle=False, random_state=42, 
                       max_iter=20000, momentum=0.7, early_stopping=True, 
                       validation_fraction=0.15)


    nhn_scores = []
    for _ in range(n):

        df_train = shuffle(df_train)
        score = np.sqrt(-cross_val_score(mlp, df_train[feature_cols], 
                    df_train[response_cols], 
                    cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')).mean()
        nhn_scores.append(score)
    score_dict[nhn] = nhn_scores
```

Then convert `score_dict` to a dataframe like this using [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

```
import pandas as pd
score_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(score_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It solves the problem with getting the dataframe of scores. But, can you suggest any improvement on the code itself for speeding up the processing time, say with GridSearchCV as explain in question?

Comment: Your welcome! If my answer solved your problem can you please upvote and Mark it as a correct one :-) Also, I need  to check about the optimization part. Can you provide the data so that I can replicate this on my system ?